# Getting error chrome not reachable from docker

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run selenium test on chrome from a python application. This works fine if I run on standalone python server. When I create the docker image and try to execute from there I get an error like this

`2017-10-03 21:18:49 - DEBUG :: Thread-1 : Error occured: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513 (2c63aa53b2c658de596ed550eb5267ec5967b351),platform=Linux 4.4.84-boot2docker x86_64)`.

I saw a couple of answers on SO which suggest to add the `--no-sandbox and --disable-setuid-sandbox` arguments to the chrome options but I still face that error when I try running my image.

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = '/app/webdrivers/linux/32/chromedriver'
    #options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    #options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

I have the chrome driver installed and its present in my docker app folder and also i have copied to the `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` just to see if that would solve my problem.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: is Chrome installed in your docker?

Comment: You need to install Chrome and XVFB inside the container and then only it can work. Also the better approach is to use a separate container for `selenium/standalone-chrome`

Comment: @Beomi Yes chrome has been installed

Comment: @TarunLalwani Can you please explain why its a better approach to use a different container ?

Comment: How about using `headless` mode?

Comment: @Beomi  I have tried that. Its still doesnt work

Comment: @TarunLalwani I installed XVFB also. It still doesnt work. Is there anything else i need to do  ?

Answer (score 2):

ChromeOptions.binary should be chrome binary not chrome driver and you only need it for headless mode.
Hope it helps.